# How to convert a value from a range input field to currency format

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert the output of the range from the input field to a Currency Format in Js. The Numbers are displaying correctly but I will like to convert it to Number Format on the output

```js
const slider = document.getElementById("idc");
const value = document.getElementById("idk");
value.textContent = slider.value;
slider.oninput = function() {
  value.textContent = this.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="range" min="0" max="5000000" id="idc" step="1000" value="0">
<h4>$</h4>
<h4 id="idk">0</h4>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format numbers as currency strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```js
const slider = document.getElementById("idc");
const value = document.getElementById("idk");
value.textContent = slider.value;
slider.oninput = function() {
  value.textContent = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(this.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="range" min="0" max="5000000" id="idc" step="1000" value="0">
<h4>$</h4>
<h4 id="idk">0</h4>
```